# URLDownloadToFile supposedly works, but file is corrupt or not right

Tags: excel, download, vba

I have been using the URLDownloadToFile function successfully for over a year, but recently it just stopped working (or something with the network did).

The relevant line of code:
`success = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, Target, 0, 0)`

Upon trying to open it I get the following message:

> Excel cannot open the file 'wkbk.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

When I open up the file in my text editor, I see that it's really HTML:
***I have star'd out the domain and the path for `window.location...` for security reasons***

```
<script src="/edms/scripts/JRETest.js"></script>
<script>

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + ";domain=***;path=/";
}    

if (JRETest.versionCheck('1.8+')) {
    setCookie("JRECookie", "1.7", 5);
} else if (JRETest.versionCheck('1.7+')) {
    setCookie("JRECookie", "1.7", 5);
} else if (JRETest.versionCheck('1.6+')) {
    setCookie("JRECookie", "1.6", 5);
} else  {
    setCookie("JRECookie", "1.6", 5);
}
window.location = "<link that I passed to URLDownloadToFile>";

</script> 
</html>
```

But the thing is, when I put in the URL for the file into my browser, it automatically downloads it just like it always did, so the URL is correct, and if I run this `GetURLStatus` function, it returns `200 - OK`

```
Function GetURLStatus(ByVal URL As String, Optional AllowRedirects As Boolean)
    Const WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString = 0
    Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

    On Error Resume Next
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
        Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = AllowRedirects

    'Clear any pervious web page source information
    PageSource = ""

    'Add protocol if missing
    If InStr(1, URL, "://") = 0 Then
        URL = "http://" & URL
    End If

    'Launch the HTTP httpRequest synchronously
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      'Handle connection errors
        GetURLStatus = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Send the http httpRequest for server status
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Send
    httpRequest.WaitForResponse
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' Handle server errors
        PageSource = "Error"
        GetURLStatus = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
      'Show HTTP response info
        GetURLStatus = httpRequest.Status & " - " & httpRequest.StatusText
      'Save the web page text
        PageSource = httpRequest.responsetext
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Like I said, this all worked before, so I don't know if the internal script changed or if it's probably with our internal documentation system, and if there's any other way I can call URLDownloadToFile to either wait for a bit until the location changes, or what is really going on.

Comment: I would say one of your administrators started playing with your company proxy ... Have you tried to open F12 and start a network trace while you enter the link into the browser ? I believe you will see some redirects there which the browser can copy with but not your download script.

Comment: Brilliant! That must have been what happened, because using one of the redirect request URLs I was able to get the right file. If you want to make this an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know similar behavior from sites where a conditions of use page or some tracking is enabled. Perhaps one of your administrators started playing with your company proxy during the last days.

Open the developer tools of your browser (normally the F12 key leads you there) and start a network trace while you open one of the urls in the browser that do no longer work.

I believe you will see some redirects there which the browser can cope with but not your download script.
Try to use the last redirect url for your script, this should work if no session key or something is created during the first call.
An alternative to this would be making your script react to redirects.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct, but it also appears that the URLs I was trying yesterday that didn't work DO work today, so it may also be tied to something with Single Sign-On or Windows Authentication. I had tried clearing cache and cookies yesterday, but I did have to restart my computer this morning, so maybe it was an SSO issue that fixed itself when I restarted. In any case, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

It could be a cache issue. My experience with "URLDownloadToFile" is that I need to first call "DeleteUrlCacheEntry(downLoadURL)" to make sure there the cache isn't messing up my tests.